# Putting varchars from a result set into an ArrayList

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to fetch data from one particular column in my table and then creating an arrayList out of it. I'm doing this because I need to be able to search through the contents of the result set.

So I fetch the result set , then perform a getArray on it to fetch data for that column as an array,

```
regionValidRS.getArray("REGION")
```

but it gives me this exception :

`Invalid column type: getARRAY not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CVarcharAccessor`

From what I understand , I think it means that the method to fetch varchars as arrays is not implemented.
i.e. I cannot use the getArray method for this and will have to manually loop through all elements to insert them into an ArrayList.

Is there another way to do this ? Preferably a faster method which would not involve looping through all elements ?

Comment: If you are fetching from a varchar column, you should use `getString()`. Perhaps you should consider doing your search on the database side.

Comment: getString can only be used to fetch one record at a time and I am deliberately avoiding doing searches on the DB side because of performance considerations.

Comment: That's true. You would have to iterate over the `ResultSet` to fetch all the rows. Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you could post some more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getArray doesn't do what you think it does. Here's what [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> Retrieves the value of the designated column **in the current row** of
>   this ResultSet object as an Array object in the Java programming
>   language.
>
> Returns: an Array object representing **the SQL ARRAY value** in the
>   specified column

(emphasis mine).

You must loop through the result set. That's the only way.

Comment: Apparently so , I must have missed the "in the current row" part when I was reading about the method !
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

To select values from a `Varchar` column and a thoose to an `ArrayList` use the following:

```
String sql = "Select yourCol From yourTable";
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
try(Connection con = getConnection(); PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement(sql)){      
    try(ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery()){
    while (rs.next()){
            results.add(rs.getString(1));
    }
}
```

I would suggest to do any processing on the database side, though.

Comment: Hmm, Yes , that seems to be the only way to go ! That's what I was doing initially, it just seemed an inelegant solution to the problem! As I said earlier , I do not wish to process on the database side because of some performance concerns!
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `getArray` method is meant for reading the value of an  ARRAY column from the current row.  (Few databases implement an array type and many people don't know about them.) You are trying to use it with a varchar column and it just doesnt work like that.

What you have to do in this case is loop through the rows of the the result set. In each row you obtain the value if the column with getString. You store the string in the list you're building. There is no faster way.

Comment: Huh, how did I not see the other answers. Oh well.